# Error uploading to appstore using pilot on fastlane

Tags: ios, fastlane

I'm having issues using pilot on testflight. I'm currently being displayed with this error:

```
 ERROR ITMS-90054: "This bundle is invalid. The bundle identifier cannot be changed from the previous version. If you want to change your bundle identifier, you will need to create a new application in iTunes Connect."
ERROR ITMS-90186: "Invalid Pre-Release Train. The train version '10.4.0' is closed for new build submissions"
ERROR ITMS-90062: "This bundle is invalid. The value for key CFBundleShortVersionString [10.4.0] in the Info.plist file must contain a higher version than that of the previously approved version [10.4.0]."
[19:06:19]: ERROR ITMS-90054: "This bundle is invalid. The bundle identifier cannot be changed from the previous version. If you want to change your bundle identifier, you will need to create a new application in iTunes Connect."
ERROR ITMS-90186: "Invalid Pre-Release Train. The train version '10.4.0' is closed for new build submissions"
ERROR ITMS-90062: "This bundle is invalid. The value for key CFBundleShortVersionString [10.4.0] in the Info.plist file must contain a higher version than that of the previously approved version [10.4.0]."
Return status of iTunes Transporter was 1: ERROR ITMS-90054: "This bundle is invalid. The bundle identifier cannot be changed from the previous version. If you want to change your bundle identifier, you will need to crea\nERROR ITMS-90186: "Invalid Pre-Release Train. The train version '10.4.0' is closed for new build submissions\nERROR ITMS-90062: "This bundle is invalid. The value for key CFBundleShortVersionString [10.4.0] in the Info.plist file must contain a higher version than that of the previously approved version [10.4.0]."
The call to the iTMSTransporter completed with a non-zero exit status: 1. This indicates a failure.
```

The code in my fastfile is like so:

```
lane :beta do
    # match(type: "appstore") # more information: https://codesigning.guide
    gym(scheme: "MyApp UAT", output_directory: build_folder)
    puts "Uploading latest build to TestFlight..."
    pilot
    # sh "your_script.sh"
    # You can also use other beta testing services here (run `fastlane actions`)
  end
```

I have a number of targets in my project and MyApp UAT is one of them (the dev target). Any ideas what I might be doing wrong here? I have tried bumping the build number in the MyApp UAT target but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

Is `scheme` the correct place to be setting the target?

Comment: well if you'd read the error output, it clearly says you don't have an app with the same bundle id in the itunes connect.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to upload an already version uploaded.

You are trying some kind of override the same version which is not allowed

> ERROR ITMS-90186: "Invalid Pre-Release Train. The train version '10.4.0' is closed for new build submissions"
>
> ERROR ITMS-90062: "This bundle is invalid. The value for key CFBundleShortVersionString [10.4.0] in the Info.plist file must contain a higher version than that of the previously approved version [10.4.0]."

Upload your BuildNumber or your versionName on your project and try it again.